# Loop authentication wifi Asus K56CB

Tags: wireless, asus, iwlwifi

I try to connect to my wifi, then I input password, it try to connect and then ask to input my password again. So I can't connect.
My wifi adapter is Intel 2030m and Laptop is Asus K56CB, Ubuntu 17.10. Also I try at Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18.3. But on Windows all was good.

### Wireless info

- [Wireless Info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FMX244FXHd/)

**

### Resolve!

**
The reason of problem was my router or driver for laptop on ubuntu. Because when I change radiochannel in wifi settings from auto to one of 1-15, my laptop connect sometimes and work. Then I install windows and my connection become normal.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: I believe Intel 2030m is your processor, not your wifi adapter. Please edit your question to add the result f the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, sorry I missed
[img]https://i.imgur.com/I9Etdri.png[/img]

Comment: @David Foerster, I added wifi info. Please, can you check it?

Comment: Thanks so far! Could you please try to associate with the wireless network, then run `sudo dmesg | grep -Ee 'iwlwifi|80211|\<wl\>' | tee /tmp/wifi.log` and add the content of `/tmp/wifi.log` to your question (or a link to a pastie if it's too long)? Can you associate this device with other wireless access points successfully? Can you try to disable the access point encryption temporarily and check if you can associate with it successfully? Thanks.

Comment: @David Foerster, I added wifi.log, please, check it

Comment: @David Foerster, yes i can connect to wifi from other devices and I also have another laptop Asus K53S with ubuntu 16.04 and connected to wifi without problems

Comment: @David Foerster, yes just a moment

Comment: @David Foerster, I updated, can u check please?

Comment: @David Foerster, sorry i missed again and now I updated what you ask

Comment: "disassociated from <MAC 'max595_2G' [AC9]> (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)" Did you change the password? Has the router been reset to default password? Can you delete the system connection, reboot and try again? `sudo rm  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/max595_2G`

Comment: @chili555, yes I changed my password on wifi and was the same. Just I tried to delete system connections how you said but after reboot was the same

Comment: @David Foerster, hi! I founded that when i choose different radiochannel in wifi settings, my laptop connected to it. But after reboot laptop, it couldn't connect and tried 2-3 times to do it. But now it was without asking password everytime trying to connect. I tried to change different settings but it didin't help. Maybe you can give me some advices, please? Also I tried to connect my iphone hotspot on my laptop and it connected

Comment: @chili555, hi! I founded that when i choose different radiochannel in wifi settings, my laptop connected to it. But after reboot laptop, it couldn't connect and tried 2-3 times to do it. But now it was without asking password everytime trying to connect. I tried to change different settings but it didin't help. Maybe you can give me some advices, please? Also I tried to connect my iphone hotspot on my laptop and it connected

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.